# Multi paging in jQuery mobile error.. for android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to do multi page application for android with PhoneGap,jQuery-mobile...
but i get that my pages @statify@ (don't know how it's called) -[image]

what can be wrong??
i used this tutorial: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/multipage-template.html
here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.5.0.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<script>

$('#greengamebtn').live('tap',function(event) {

    $('#textpage1').removeClass('red').addClass("green");

});

$('#redgamebtn').live('tap',function(event) {

    $('#textpage1').removeClass('green').addClass("red");

});

$('#exitgamebtn').live('tap',function(event) {

    navigator.app.exitApp();

});

</script>
</head>
<body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1><p class="red" id="textpage1">PAGE 1</p></h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="button" id="redgamebtn" "><h2> RED</h2></div>
            <div data-role="button" id="greengamebtn" "><h2> GREEN</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div page-role="page" id="page2"  data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1><p class="red" id="textpage2">PAGE 2</p></h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="button" id="exitgamebtn" "><h2> Exit game</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from the screenshot that the JQM library is not loaded. Just to see if I'm right try replacing

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
```

with this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure if this matters but notice that I used JQuery 1.6.4. That is the recommended version to use with JQM 1.0.1. If that works then check your paths and try again. I hope this helps!

Comment: hm.. now is working like the Page1 is shown at top and Page2 at bottom... and divs - RED and GREEN are not recognized like a button and don't work..

Comment: What happens when you remove cordova and your custom style?

Comment: ok.. i already made it.. you were right, jq-mobile didn't work properly.. maybe because of jq version.. i downloaded JQ 1.6.4 and now it is working like it must... thank you